# Split output variable into similarly sized dataframes and merge those

Tags: python, pandas, gurobi

My problem: Trying to **split an output variable into similarly sized dataframes and merge those**.

Model output: "var"

```
{('Product1', 0): <gurobi.Var listing[Product1,0] (value 1.0)>, ('Product1', 1): <gurobi.Var listing[Product1,1] (value 0.0)>, ('Product1', 2): <gurobi.Var listing[Product1,2] (value 0.0)>, ('Product1', 3): <gurobi.Var listing[Product1,3] (value 0.0)>, ('Product2', 0): <gurobi.Var listing[Product2,0] (value 1.0)>, ('Product2', 1): <gurobi.Var listing[Product2,1] (value 0.0)>, ('Product2', 2): <gurobi.Var listing[Product2,2] (value 0.0)>, ('Product2', 3): <gurobi.Var listing[Product2,3] (value 0.0)>, ('Product3', 0): <gurobi.Var listing[Product3,0] (value 1.0)>, ('Product3', 1): <gurobi.Var listing[Product3,1] (value 0.0)>, ('Product3', 2): <gurobi.Var listing[Product3,2] (value 0.0)>, ('Product3', 3): <gurobi.Var listing[Product3,3] (value 0.0)>}
<class 'gurobipy.tupledict'>
```

Desired output:
The desired output should look like this:

```
                    0    1    2    3                                
Product1          1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Product2          1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Product3          0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

My (very manual) attempt:

1) I turned the output variable into a dataframe "df_listing":

```
dict_listing = {k : v.X for k,v in var.items()}
df_listing = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_listing, orient='index')
df_listing = df_listing.rename(columns = {0: 'listing'})

               listing
(Product1, 0)      1.0
(Product1, 1)      0.0
(Product1, 2)      0.0
(Product1, 3)      0.0
(Product2, 0)      1.0
(Product2, 1)      0.0
(Product2, 2)      0.0
(Product2, 3)      0.0
(Product3, 0)      0.0
(Product3, 1)      0.0
(Product3, 2)      0.0
(Product3, 3)      1.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

2) Transpose "df_listing":

```
df_listing = df_listing.transpose()
```

3) Use k, which is the number of columns - in this case it is 4 --> 0,1,2,3

```
df_Product1 = df_listing.iloc[:, 0*k:1*k]
df_Product1.columns = list(range(k))
df_Product2 = df_listing.iloc[:, 1*k:2*k]
df_Product2.columns = list(range(k))
df_Product3 = df_listing.iloc[:, 2*k:3*k]
df_Product3.columns = list(range(k))
```

4) Concatenate the three dataframes

```
input = [df_Product1, df_Product2, df_Product3]
df_facingsProductAll = pd.concat(input)
```

My attempt was very manual, so I am looking for a) a more **automized solution**, probably using a for loop and b) have a more **dynamic code so that the input could be more products**, e.g. 5 products,

Thanks for your help guys and girls!

Comment: It looks like a you could use `pd.pivot_table`.

Comment: I think the answer you want is a combination of `reset_index` and reformatting your column with the `(Product1, 0)` type entries and then using `pivot_table` create one row per product. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Can you show user your input dataframe using .to_dict() `df_listing.to_dict()` and paste the output in this question.  Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting a tuple in your dataframe index instead of a multiindex.  Can you also show the code that used to generate this dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston Just did that, hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try from this

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """
               listing
(Product1,0)      1.0
(Product1,1)      0.0
(Product1,2)      0.0
(Product1,3)      0.0
(Product2,0)      1.0
(Product2,1)      0.0
(Product2,2)      0.0
(Product2,3)      0.0
(Product3,0)      0.0
(Product3,1)      0.0
(Product3,2)      0.0
(Product3,3)      1.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

df = df.reset_index()

# split index and concat to df

df = pd.concat([df,
                pd.DataFrame(df["index"].str.split(",")\
                                        .values.tolist(),
                             columns=["a","b"])],
                axis=1)

df = df.drop("index", axis=1)

# remove brackets
df["a"] = df["a"].str[1:]
df["b"] = df["b"].str[:-1].astype(int)

out = pd.pivot_table(df,
                     index="a",
                     columns="b",
                     values="listing")
```

Output

```py
b           0    1    2    3
a                           
Product1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Product2  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
Product3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

**UPDATE**

In case you have a whitespace as `(Product1, 0)` you can procede as following:

```py
txt = """
               listing
(Product1, 0)      1.0
(Product1, 1)      0.0
(Product1, 2)      0.0
(Product1, 3)      0.0
(Product2, 0)      1.0
(Product2, 1)      0.0
(Product2, 2)      0.0
(Product2, 3)      0.0
(Product3, 0)      0.0
(Product3, 1)      0.0
(Product3, 2)      0.0
(Product3, 3)      1.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), delim_whitespace=True)

df = df.reset_index()\
       .rename(columns={"level_0":"a",
                        "level_1":"b"})
# remove brackets
df["a"] = df["a"].str[1:-1]
df["b"] = df["b"].str[:-1].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @rpanai

I've got one more question on this: My index has a blank space, i.e. it is in the form of :
´(Product1, 0)      1.0´
and not in the form of:
´(Product1,0)      1.0´

Simply adding a blank space to the str.split (", ") did not help unfortunately. How would you go about this?

Comment: @MUCSP_90 check the updated answer and eventually upvote it if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version of your example data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': [('Product 1' , 0), ('Product 1', 1) , ('Product 2', 0), ('Product 2', 1)],
                   'listing': [1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]})
df
```

[image]
Then reset the index column to split the product name from the 'index'

```
df['prod_indx'] = df['product'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['product'] = df['product'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

[image]

Then pivot

```
output = pd.pivot_table(df, values='listing', columns='prod_indx', index='product', aggfunc=sum)
print(output)
```

[image]